# Test C# app without locally installed libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I hope this is no duplicate but I couldn't find any related topic. Every developer knows the problem. I create my app, deploy it and on some other machine it does not run because some dependency is missing. Often those dependecies are part of the workloads installed along with Visual Studio or some SDKs.

My question now is if there is a way to test my app on my dev machine like it had not installed SDKs and VS? Basically I want the app to only consider dependencies I explicitely specified through project references, nuget packages or locally copied files. Or in short: every dependency should be part of the app's deployment target folder.

Of course some really basic OS-dependent stuff needs to be used as well but I don't want the app to use stuff like OpenAL, GLFW, Windows SDK or similiar things just because I have installed it on my machine beforehand.

I hope you can understand what I mean. So I basically need some sandbox. I know there are things like VMs, docker, etc but I would like to use this as I run my app from Visual Studio. So if I hit F5 I want the app to ignore globally installed stuff at all.

I work with VS 2022. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Part of the robust build pipeline should make an appropriate package to install. For some definition of package and install. This is made much easier for many workflows with dotnetcore and nuget packages.

Comment: This is *very* hard to provide anything like a concrete answer without knowing what kind of application it is. I've found that `dotnet publish` is a good starting point, but it really depends on the application.

Comment: It is a NET6 console app which uses glfw + opengl and therefore has some native dependencies. I publish as a single file (which worked in netcore3.1) but since NET6, native libs are not added into the file by default. The problem is, that I won't notice that they are missing when I only provide the single exe, when I have those libs installed globally. And this was exactly what happened. I want to avoid all cases where a program I wrote only runs because I installed some global library.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a continuous integration system in order to build (from scratch), publish and test on a fixed known build agent configuration. I used Teamcity.

You could use a Virtual Machine or a docker image as agent PC.

Moreover you can configure more agents with different possible configurations.

Comment: The problem with CI is time. It takes quite a while to run a whole pipeline just to test if the app runs. Of course in general you only need to do so after some bigger change or added reference, so maybe it's the way to go. I just hoped for something that can be done out of the box in VS or a plugin or tool. Or even some kind of configuration setting within VS or the project.

Comment: Ok so using CI, how would I test if for example a game would run? I don't want to write tests in this case as I explicitly want to check if the whole game can be started without exceptions? I guess I could check the exit code and let the pipeline fail if it is not 0. But what if the game runs? It would keep running. Something like a command line argument came to mind which closes the app early. Are there best practices for such case?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, you can reference Nuget packages instead of assemblies in the GAC.  This way, they will be copied to your application's bin folder.

You can also use .NET Application Publishing to create a deployable folder with your application.  If you're targeting .NET Core, and the target machine may not have .NET Core installed or you don't know what version it will have, you can create a self contained release which will include the .NET Core binaries in the release.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: But if I miss a GAC assembly via nuget I still will be able to start the app on my local machine. But others won't. And this is what I want to avoid. Publishing is good but it still has flaws especially with native dependencies. I would prefer something like a clean state execution but without the need of VMs or even CI.

Comment: I think you've hit on the solution with your comment.  Don't miss a GAC assembly and bundle everything with the app.  The alternative is to use an installer to detect missing dependencies and install them at deploy time. Having built a lot of installers over the years and targeted both .NET Framework and .NET Core, I found it's easiest and simplest to just bundle everything with app. The main drawback is file size.   Deployment is an important part of the development process and if you're doing any more than a handful of deployments it's worth spending time on to get it right.

Comment: But often the problem is exactly to know what dependencies there are. Sure you will know the dependencies you added but not always those which were added by other dependencies or by the runtime itself. In my case I used Silk.NET which needs glfw or SDL. If you have them already installed you won't know that they are missing or even needed. You will only know when someone else fails to start your app. I would know if those installed versions wouldn't be considered for local execution.